# Azure Pipeline can't find nuget package in test but has no problem in build

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-functions

I'm trying to setup a pipeline to deploy my app, but before I'ld like to run all TestCases.

Now, the build and deploy works, but if I activate the test step, I receive an error that my nuget package could not be found. This nuget package is delivered by my own azure nuget storage and in the build step, it works.

ErrorMessage received:

```
D:\a\1\s\myFolder\myProject.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package my.nupack.Db. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org [D:\a\1\s\myFolder.Test\myProject.Test.csproj]
  Failed to restore D:\a\1\s\myFolder\myProject.csproj (in 1.04 sec).
  Failed to restore D:\a\1\s\myFolder.Test\myProject.Test.csproj (in 1.09 sec).
  Restored D:\a\1\s\myFolder2\myProject2.csproj (in 8 ms).
```

The pipeline looks as follows:

```
# ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework)
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting the full .NET Framework.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- main

variables:
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  projectNameFunctionApp: 'My.Project.Analysis'

    # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'windows-latest'

  # Working Directory
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
  solution: '$(workingDirectory)/My.Project.sln'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      inputs:
        version: 6.0.x
    
    - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 6.3.0
    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      displayName: 'NuGet restore'
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        restoreSolution: '**\*.sln'
        feedsToUse: 'select'
        vstsFeed: '{VSTS-UUID, I removed it}'
        
    - task: VSBuild@1
      displayName: Build
      inputs:
        solution: '**\*.sln'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Run Visual studio tests
      inputs:
        command: test
        projects: '**/*My.Project.Test*/*.csproj'
        arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive $(projectNameFunctionApp)'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/$(projectNameFunctionApp)/bin/$(buildConfiguration)/net6.0"
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip"

    - publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop
```

Any ideas, why the nuget package is recognized in restore and build, but not in the .test-Project?

Remark: The Test-Project currently just includes simple tests, not requireing the package at all.

Comment: `dotnet restore` and `nuget restore` are different tools. You're mixing building with Visual Studio and testing with `dotnet`. Try using a single toolset for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Sample YAML code that shows how to use `nuget restore` in Azure Pipelines:

```yaml
variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
steps:
- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: true
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: 'NuGet.config'
```

`dotnet restore` is used for NuGet Packages and project related packages. but `nuget restore` is to get only NuGet packages.

To know more information about both the commands, Refer to MS Doc [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore) & [2.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore)